# iNotes redirect to own address when I use reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, ibm-domino

I am trying to set up reverse proxy for Domino iNotes. I want use adress email-test.domain.com It works until I log in. After it redirect me back to email.domain.com. How can I keep my proxy adress and SLL certificate ?

Here is my settings on proxy server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName email-test.domain.com
        Redirect / https://email-test.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName email-test.domain.com
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_email.log vcombined
        ProxyRequests off
        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyPass / https://email.domain.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://email.domain.com/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SetOutputFilter proxy-html
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what's the whole url scheme it redirects you to?

Comment: Do you use a iwaredir.nsf? If yes: How is it configured? You need to use "Dynamic" as type if you want to keep thr url after redirection...

Comment: ezra-s: it starts with this url https://email-test.domain.com/iwaredir.nsf?Open  after redirecting is https://email.domain.com/mail/jrychtar.nsf?OpenDatabase

Comment: Torsten Link: It is set Fixed.When I switch to Dynanamic its not work even at Apache proxy which is on Domino server

Answer (score 0):

After redirecting if I change url in browser to email-test it works

So I tryed add rewrite:

`RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !email.domain.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://email-test.domain.com$1 [R]`

But no success. It creates loop. Any suggestions ?